# What does "$L^p$ is a quasi-Banach space" mean? ($0<p<1)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I read from a Forier Analysis book that the space $L^p(\Omega)$ is a *quasi-Banach space* for $p\in (0,1)$. The book mentions that $||\cdot||_p$ is a *quasi-norm*, which means that
$$
||f+g||_p \le C (||f||_p + ||g||_p)
$$
for some $C\ge 1$ (of course, one can easily prove that $C=2^{\frac 1p-1}$ works here). However, it was not mentioned explicitly what a quasi-Banach space means.

> What is the definition of a **quasi-Banach space** and how do we prove that $L^p(\Omega)$ is quasi-complete for $p\in(0,1)$?

I can guess what the phrase ought to mean but I am not completely sure.

Comment: [Aoki-Rolewicz Theorem's](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/157_07_JIPAM/157_07.pdf) says that there is a quasi-norm $|\|\cdot\||$, equivalent to $\|\cdot\|$ such that $|\|x+y\||^p\leq|\|x\||^p+|\|y\||^p$. Then you can repeat the proof of completeness with this other quasi-norm. The quasi-norm $|\|\cdot\||$ can be defined by $|\|x\||=\inf\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n}\|x_i\|^p\right)^{1/p}$ for all $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_i=x$.

Comment: A word by word reference for "quasi-Banach Space" for me is that you have a "complete vector metric space" with an induced metric from "a quasi-norm".

[link](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/lpspace.pdf). Appendix A, page 14 will help I guess.

Note: Please feel free to edit this comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a vector space together with a quasi-norm $\|\cdot\|_{quasi}$. One can show (Aoki-Rolewicz Theorem) that there exists $r \in (0,1]$ such that $d(x,y) := \|x-y\|^r_{quasi}$ is a metric. In particular, we can ask if $(X,d)$ is complete and then we say that $(X,d)$ is a quasi-Banach space.

In our special case, one can define a metric on $L^p(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, $0 < p <1$, via
$$d(f,g):= \int |f-g|^p \, d \mu.$$
This metric is invariant under translations (i.e. $d(f-h,g-h) = d(f,g)$), but not a norm. In particular, $L^p$ is a topological vector space. Using the same arguments as in the proof of the completness of $L^p$ with $p \geq 1$, one can show that $L^p$ is complete with respect to the metric $d$.

The interesting part here is that it is possible to show that $(L^p)^* = \{0\}$ for measures $\mu$ without atoms. Thus, in view of Banach's extension theorems, there is no norm on $L^p$ inducing the above-mentioned topology. In particular, $L^p$ is for $0 <p <1 $ not a locally convex topological vector space.